# How to apply rating stars into UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi I want apply rating stars into `UITableViewCell`.

Is any sample available for it?

I tried some code but it's not working.

Please help.

## My Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "starsInCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    starsInCell *cell;
    NSMutableArray *mainArray,*BtnsArray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize TableList;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TableList.delegate = self;
    TableList.dataSource = self;
    mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"", @"",@"",@"",nil];
    BtnsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"false",@"false",@"false",@"false",@"false", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return mainArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell =[TableList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"starsInCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    //cell.textLabel.text = @"1";
    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];


    NSString *btn1str = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *btn2str = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *btn3str = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *btn4str = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *btn5str = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:4];

    [self setImages:btn1str :cell.btn1];
    [self setImages:btn2str :cell.btn2];
    [self setImages:btn3str :cell.btn3];
    [self setImages:btn4str :cell.btn4];
    [self setImages:btn5str :cell.btn5];


    [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn2Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn3Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn4Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn5Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 80;
}

-(void)btn1Clicked:(UIButton*)button{
    NSLog(@"Action performed");
    //NSLog(@"button position is =====> %d",mainArray.count);

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:TableList];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TableList indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    int buttonValue = button.tag;
    NSString *string1 = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:buttonValue];
    for (int i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++) {
        if (indexPath.row == i){

            if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"false"]){
                [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:buttonValue withObject:@"true"];
            }else{
                for (int i = buttonValue+1; i < BtnsArray.count; i++){
                    [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"false"];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    [TableList reloadData];

}
-(void)btn2Clicked:(UIButton*)button{
    NSLog(@"Action performed");
    //NSLog(@"button position is =====> %d",mainArray.count);

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:TableList];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TableList indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    int buttonValue = button.tag;
    NSString *string1 = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:buttonValue];
    for (int i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++) {
        if (indexPath.row == i){

            if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"false"]){
                [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:buttonValue withObject:@"true"];
            }else{
                for (int i = buttonValue+1; i < BtnsArray.count; i++){
                    [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"false"];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    [TableList reloadData];

}
-(void)btn3Clicked:(UIButton*)button{
    NSLog(@"Action performed");
    //NSLog(@"button position is =====> %d",mainArray.count);

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:TableList];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TableList indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    int buttonValue = button.tag;
    NSString *string1 = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:buttonValue];
    for (int i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++) {
        if (indexPath.row == i){

            if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"false"]){
                [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:buttonValue withObject:@"true"];
            }else{
                for (int i = buttonValue+1; i < BtnsArray.count; i++){
                    [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"false"];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    [TableList reloadData];

}
-(void)btn4Clicked:(UIButton*)button{
    NSLog(@"Action performed");
    //NSLog(@"button position is =====> %d",mainArray.count);

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:TableList];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TableList indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    int buttonValue = button.tag;
    NSString *string1 = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:buttonValue];
    for (int i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++) {
        if (indexPath.row == i){

            if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"false"]){
                [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:buttonValue withObject:@"true"];
            }else{
                for (int i = buttonValue+1; i < BtnsArray.count; i++){
                    [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"false"];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    [TableList reloadData];

}
-(void)btn5Clicked:(UIButton*)button{
    NSLog(@"Action performed");
    //NSLog(@"button position is =====> %d",mainArray.count);

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:TableList];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TableList indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    int buttonValue = button.tag;
    NSString *string1 = [BtnsArray objectAtIndex:buttonValue];
    for (int i=0; i < mainArray.count; i++) {
        if (indexPath.row == i){

            if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"false"]){
                [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:buttonValue withObject:@"true"];
            }else{
                for (int i = buttonValue+1; i < BtnsArray.count; i++){
                    [BtnsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"false"];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    [TableList reloadData];

}
-(void)setImages:(NSString*)string1 :(UIButton*)button1{

    if ([string1 isEqualToString:@"false"]){
        [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried to do so. You can use buttons having set two image for both selected and default state and then manage the image accordingly.

Comment: do you want to allow users to give rate or just want to show rating ?

Comment: Hi  ivarun,Yes. i want to allow users to give rating.

Comment: Hi Bharat Modi, i tried but it is not working.can i send my code to you

Comment: Just post your code along with your question.

Comment: I posted my code please see once

Comment: Anil you can use this simple and easy library for Rating https://github.com/glenyi/TPFloatRatingView

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do this yourself only if you are new in development and you want to build your logic, so instead of using any readymade library you can follow below steps.

1. First add 5 buttons on your cell and set bordered star image for each buttons default state and then change buttons state to Selected and set filled star image. (Do same for 5 buttons). After you done this make sure you change all buttons state to Default.
2. Add action **buttonStarRatingsClicked** for all 5 buttons.
3. Create outlet collection **buttonCollectionStarRatings** for each button in starsInCell class.
4. Add below method in your viewController which is showing tableView having stars on each cell.

   ```
   - (IBAction)buttonStarRatingsClicked:(id)sender {

   UIButton *buttonStarRatings = (UIButton*) sender;

   //Here you will need to get cell to access buttonCollectionStarRatings
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[buttonStarRatings superView] superView];
   //Check is clicked button is selected
   if ([buttonStarRatings isSelected]) {


   if (buttonStarRatings.tag == 0) { //Check is clicked button is first button

       //Check if Next button of selected button is selected
       if ([cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings[buttonStarRatings.tag+1] isSelected]) {

           @autoreleasepool {

               for (int i = (int)buttonStarRatings.tag+1; i < [cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings count]; i++) {
                   UIButton *buttonStarRating = cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings[i];
                   [buttonStarRating setSelected:NO];
               }
           }

       } else {
           //If selected button is first button and is selected then do not take any action as atlease one star should be selected.
       }

   } else if (buttonStarRatings.tag == 4) { //Check is clicked button is last button

       [buttonStarRatings setSelected:NO];

   } else { //Selected button is one of the button between first and last

       //Check if Next button of selected button is selected
       if ([cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings[buttonStarRatings.tag+1] isSelected]) {

           @autoreleasepool {

               for (int i = (int)buttonStarRatings.tag; i < [cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings count]; i++) {
                   UIButton *buttonStarRating = cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings[i];
                   [buttonStarRating setSelected:NO];
               }
           }
       } else {
           [buttonStarRatings setSelected:NO];
       }
   }
   } else {

   if (buttonStarRatings.tag == 0) { //Check is clicked button is first button

       [buttonStarRatings setSelected:YES];
   } else if (buttonStarRatings.tag == 4) { //Check is clicked button is last button

       @autoreleasepool {

           for (UIButton *buttonStarRating in cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings) {
               [buttonStarRating setSelected:YES];
           }
       }
   } else { //Selected button is one of the button between first and last

       @autoreleasepool {

           for (int i = 0; i <= (int)buttonStarRatings.tag; i++) {
               UIButton *buttonStarRating = cell.buttonCollectionStarRatings[i];
               [buttonStarRating setSelected:YES];
           }
       }
   }
   }
   }
   ```

The above part will allow you to select star ratings on each cell, next step is managing the selected stars on each cell while scrolling the table.